# Cannot create a persistent Bluetooth connection between phone and laptop using rfcomm

Tags: bluetooth, android, connection, phone, smartphone

I already successfully paired my Android (6.0.1) phone (Sony Xperia Z3) with my laptop (running Ubuntu 14.04). I can send files back and forth. The Bluetooth connection menu shows that the connection switch switches to ON if files are sent.

I tried to establish a persistent conenction using:

```
sudo rfcomm connect rfcomm0 [MAC ADDRESS] 1
```

but I always get:

> Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused.

Background:
I want to send data from my phone to my laptop via Bluetooth. If I run this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899475/android-sample-bluetooth-code-to-send-a-simple-string-via-bluetooth) the switch goes on as well, but immediately closes the connection down (switch goes back to OFF).

Logcat shows the following exception:

> E/error: error init:java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might
>   closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Comment: follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489483/send-data-from-phone-to-laptop-via-bluetooth